# Sync PHP for loop iterations with twig for loop iterations in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, twig, octobercms

I'm trying to sync PHP iterations with twig iterations.

I have this foreach loop in PHP:

```
foreach ($items as $img) {
      $this['picture'] = $img;
  }
```

And this for loop in Twig:

```
{% for image in gallery %}
   {{picture}} 
{% endfor %}
```

Now my output is the same, iteration count is correct (there are 3 pictures in the folder, but only getting last one):

- img03.jpg
- img03.jpg
- img03.jpg

If I add echo in PHP:

```
foreach ($items as $img) {
     echo $this['picture'] = $img;
  }
```

Output is correct, but the content from echo is displayed above the HTML.

- img01.jpg
- img02.jpg
- img03.jpg

It's possible to display correct output inside Twig loop?

Comment: `$this['picture']` is overwriting the same value each time.

Comment: I'm new to php, is there any way to avoid this overwriting?

Comment: i guess u need to call as {{ image.picture }}.

Comment: @CodeBug Already tried that, no results from loop.

Comment: I finaly figured it out, passed whole array as page variable and looped it only with twig, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
{% for image in gallery %}
   {{**image**}} 
{% endfor %}
```